# How to use MediaStore with scoped storage to store files in Android10

Tags: android, mediastore, android-external-storage, scoped-storage

Im trying to develop an android-lib to store files in /sdcard/{Environment.DIRECTORY_*} after Android 10 has locked everything with its scoped storage.

I tried `context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` which is giving me `/sdcard/Android/data/my.company.namespace/files/Pictures`. I was assuming I could use the MediaStore to scan this Folder and gallery Apps will show Pictures from there. Unfortunately, It doesn't...

I'm reading the docs for hours, but cannot find a comprehensive guide on how to do this.

For Example:

`MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(ContentResolver, Bitmap, String, String)` is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#insertImage(android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and links to [MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#IS_PENDING) which doesn't say a word on how to use it. 
If I look inside the code, It uses a lot of classes which are non-existant, like `PendingParams`or `PendingSession` and even If I copy them they still use deprecated methods.

Is there a comprehensive guide, how to use MediaStore to save Files at their respective locations?

Say I want to store a custom image format (image/wsq) in `/sdcard/Pictures`. Or a custom binary file in `/sdcard/Documents`. It doesn't matter if other apps could access it or not.

How do I do it with `MediaStore`?

Comment: "Is there a comprehensive guide, how to use MediaStore to save Files at their respective locations?" -- [This sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/tree/v0.5/ConferenceVideos) shows how to add content to the `MediaStore` on Android 10 and lower. In my case, I am adding video content, not images, but other than the base `Uri` to use, the process should be the same for images or audio content. "Or a custom binary file in /sdcard/Documents." -- that's not an option. Let the user choose the location via `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`.

Comment: So, are you saying it is not possible to store blobs at sdcard or just not in `Documents`? Can I save files in `Download`?

Comment: You can use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, and allow the user to choose where the user wants to store the user's content. Or, you can use `getExternalFilesDirs()`. Or, for media content only, I think you can use `MediaStore` to store content on removable storage. AFAIK, those are your only options.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir. I read all of your topics regarding SAF and your stance on lazy devs not updating for years... I'm wondering, i.e. how Chrome Browser is able to write arbitary Files at /sdcard/Download without user interaction

Comment: `Say I want to store a custom image format (image/wsq) in /sdcard/Pictures. Or a custom binary file in /sdcard/Documents. It doesn't matter if other apps could access it or not.

How do I do it with MediaStore?` Did you solve this meanwhile? As all is possible.

Comment: Can anyone help me to save PDF files? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63480192/how-to-save-and-store-pdf-file-in-a-folder-using-scoped-storage-in-android-10-an